# Query failing on first try of the day, succeeding on second try

Tags: python, sql, pyramid, freetds

Exact error I get is here:

```
{'trace': "(Error) ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed (20006) (SQLExecDirectW)')"}
```

I get this when I first run a query in my Pyramid application. Any query I run (In my case, it is a web search form that returns info from a database)

The entire application is read-only, as is the account used to connect to the db. I don't know what it would be writing that would fail. And like I said, if I re-run the exact same thing (or refresh the page) it runs just fine without error.

Edit: Emphasis on the "first try of the day". If no queries for x amount of time, I get this write error again, and then it'll work. It's almost like it's fallen asleep and that first query will wake it up.

Comment: How long does it take for the error to appear?

Comment: Instantly. No lag whatsoever. Refreshing the page, takes a second, then results appear.

Comment: What happens if you telnet from the web server to the SQL Server on port `1433` before the first try?  If the telnet makes a difference, it's probably a network or DNS lookup issue.

Comment: Haven't tried that, though I think any attempts to replicate will have to wait several hours lol. Even running a build of the application on a different system will run just fine the first query, if a first query has already been run (on any other build)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that there's a pool of DB connections that is kept open for some time, T. The server, however, terminates open connections after some time, S, which is less than T.

The first connection of the day (or after S elapses in general) would give you this error.

Try to look for a way to change the "timeout" of the connections in the pool to be less than S and that should fix the problem.

Edit: These times (T and S) are dependent on configs or default values for the server and libraries you use. I've experienced a similar issue with a Flask+SQLAlchemy+MySQL app in the past and I had to change the connection timeouts, etc.

Edit 2: T might be "keep connections open forever" or a very high value

Comment: Good thought, though I think we've fixed the issue. The db is a nightly database, an exact copy of another database, restored daily at 1am. Our thinking was the db was closing the connection after each restoration, so we scheduled a restart an hour later each morning. Since this adjustment, the error has disappeared.